# "mount error(2): No such file or directory" error on attempting to mount NAS from Arch

Tags: mount, arch-linux, nas

I am attempting to mount my NAS on my Arch machine and receiving the below error:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Not seeing anything in man which helps.

Below is command I am using

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<user> //192.168.0.14/volume1/NetBackup/Share /mnt/NAS
```

I can ping the IP of the NAS. The below command:

```
smbclient -U <user> -L 192.168.0.14
```

returns the below:

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    NetBackup       Disk      System default shared folder
    photo           Disk      System default shared folder
    surveillance    Disk      System default shared folder
    video           Disk      System default shared folder
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service ()
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------
```

Right clicking the directory on the NAS displays the path as being:

```
/volume1/NetBackup/Share
```

Any ideas on what to do next to troubleshoot?

Comment: Sometimes on my computer I cannot even see directories with my shell (bash) because I’m not in a root shell. It may differ for you, and this possibly cannot work but try changing the parameter user to user=root rather than <user>.

Comment: No that didn't work. There is no root user on the NAS so I wouldn't expect it to. I tried admin too, and that didn't work either. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax might be confusing -- after the server name, you don't specify the path, but the share name, as defined in the smb.conf file at the server side. So, instead:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<user> //192.168.0.14/volume1/NetBackup/Share /mnt/NAS
```

use:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<user> //192.168.0.14/<SHARENAME> /mnt/NAS
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it turned out that I **forgot to create the share directory** 
so I created the share in the path and voila the error got fixed 
just I thought to add it as one of the possible cause of the error in case someone may benefit from it

Answer (score -2):

**ERROR**
[root@samba-client ~]# mount -t cifs -o user=smbuser //192.168.20.115/smbshare /client/
Password for smbuser@//192.168.20.115/smbshare:  ********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
[root@samba-client ~]# mount -t cifs //192.168.20.115/smbshare /client/ -o user=smbuser

**Troubleshooting**
mount -t cifs //192.168.20.115/smbshare /client/ -o user=smbuser

check your samba server configuration file: vi /etc/samba/smb.conf 
make sure the samba directory name in the square bracket is the same with the one you trying to access from the client end also ensure the path is correct. ie

**[smbshare]**

```
    comment = Samba share
    path = /smbshare
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    public = yes
```